# Programatically build XML document using XElements.Decendents()

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am writing an application that works along side word and makes a custom menu system for it.

I want the user to be able to essentially add an infinite sub menus.

I am reading in from a text file where a tab represents indenting.

Example text file:

```
GROUP
    MENU1
        SUBMENU11
               SUBSUBMENU111
                     SUBSUBMENU1111
        SUBMENU12
    MENU2
        SUBMENU21
                    SUBSUBMENU211
```

Example XML output:

```
 <group id="GROUP" label="GROUP">
      <menu id="MENU1" label="MENU1" size="normal">
        <menu id="SUBMENU11" label="SUBMENU11" size="normal" >
          <menu id="SUBMENU111" label="SUBMENU111" size="normal" >
            <menu id="SUBMENU1111" label="SUBMENU1111" size="normal" />
          </menu>
        </menu>
        <menu id="SUBMENU12" label="SUBMENU12" size="normal" />
      </menu>       
      <menu id="MENU2" label="MENU2" size="normal" >
        <menu id="SUBMENU21" label="SUBMENU21" size="normal" >
          <menu id="SUBMENU211" label="SUBMENU211" size="normal" />
        </menu>
      </menu>
    </group>
```

Currently to add at certain points ie at 5 tabs down:

```
path.Descendants(ns + "menu").ElementAt(currentMenuIndex)
                       .Descendants(ns + "menu").ElementAt(currentMenu1Index)
                           .Descendants(ns + "menu").ElementAt(currentMenu2Index)
                               .Descendants(ns + "menu").LastOrDefault()
                                   .Add(//add node info);
```

I am currently creating each of these descendant trees for each tab case, this makes the code bulky and if i can i would like to be able to do it programmatically for an infinite amount of tabs.

Any light you can shed on this would be wonderful, I've been going round in circles for days.

Comment: You example XML has not as many levels as you seem to think. When SubMenu11 is self-closing, it can't have children.

Comment: Crap thats me being a muppet! and writing bad xml!I will correct it!

Comment: Could you use a recursive function?

Comment: Your own code isn't that bad, it's the use of indices (and ElmentAt) that makes it a little awkward. XML isn't index friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [much simpler syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx) to create `XElement` and `XAttribute`s in an Xml Document

```
new XElement("group",
    new XAttribute("id", "GROUP"),
    new XElement("menu",
      new XAttribute("id", "MENU1"),
```

... etc

**Edit**
How about a recursive strategy here, with some Linq:

```
const string menu = // I've hardcoded tabs and newlines as SO formats these out.
    "GROUP\r\n" +
    "MENU1\r\n" +
    "\tSUBMENU11\r\n" +
    "\t\tSUBSUBMENU111\r\n"+
    "\t\t\tSUBSUBMENU1111\r\n" +
    "\tSUBMENU12\r\n"+
    "MENU2\r\n" +
    "\tSUBMENU21\r\n"+
    "\t\tSUBSUBMENU211";

var sr = new StringReader(menu); // Obviously use a TextReader
var lines = sr.ReadToEnd()
              .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var indentedLines =
    lines
        .Skip(1) // Group isn't part of the menu
        .Select(
        _ => new Tuple<string, int>( // Remove whitespace
            Regex.Replace(_, @"\s+", ""), 
            _.Split(new[] { '\t' }).Count())) // Count the tabs
      .ToList();

var doc = new XDocument();
doc.Add(new XElement("group", // Add the root group
           new XAttribute("id", lines[0].Trim()),
           new XAttribute("label", lines[0].Trim()),
           BuildTree(indentedLines, 1, String.Empty))); // Add the top lvl nodes
```

With this recursive helper:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> BuildTree(
     IList<Tuple<string, int>> indentedLines, 
     int indentLevel, String parentNode)
{
    Func<string, string> getNodeParent =
        node =>
            {
                var line = indentedLines.First(_ => _.Item1 == node);
                for (var index = indentedLines.IndexOf(line); index >= 0; index --)
                {
                    if (indentedLines[index].Item2 < line.Item2)
                    {
                        return indentedLines[index].Item1;
                    }
                }
                return String.Empty; // has no parent
            };
    foreach (var line in indentedLines.Where(_ => _.Item2 == indentLevel 
             && getNodeParent(_.Item1) == parentNode))
    {
        yield return new XElement("menu",
                                  new XAttribute("id", line.Item1),
                                  new XAttribute("label", line.Item1),
                                  new XAttribute("size", "normal"),
                                  BuildTree(indentedLines, indentLevel + 1, line.Item1));
    }
}
```

Produces this Xml, which I think is what you are after:

```
<group id="GROUP" label="GROUP">
  <menu id="MENU1" label="MENU1" size="normal">
    <menu id="SUBMENU11" label="SUBMENU11" size="normal">
      <menu id="SUBSUBMENU111" label="SUBSUBMENU111" size="normal">
        <menu id="SUBSUBMENU1111" label="SUBSUBMENU1111" size="normal" />
      </menu>
    </menu>
    <menu id="SUBMENU12" label="SUBMENU12" size="normal" />
  </menu>
  <menu id="MENU2" label="MENU2" size="normal">
    <menu id="SUBMENU21" label="SUBMENU21" size="normal">
      <menu id="SUBSUBMENU211" label="SUBSUBMENU211" size="normal" />
    </menu>
  </menu>
</group>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but that doesn't really answer my question as I dont see how I can programmatically create a document using that structure with just the information I get from the text file. I want the system to read in the text file then spit out the xml with me having to hardcode where it places everything.

Comment: @DMA I've coded it for you, building up the tree from the file recursively. The Tuple contains each menu's title (Item1), plus the level of indent (Item2, count of tabs).

Comment: @StuartLC Thank you so much, my understanding of all this has been very limited, I have confused my greatly in the process of trying to write this, but your responses do make it all a lot clearer. Your help is greatly appreciated! Now to spend some time to fully understanding the code!

Comment: I have to say that it wasn't quite as easy as I made out when I made the original post. The one iffy bit is the `getNodeParent` - you'll iffy results if there is more than one parent with the same name - hopefully this isn't the case. You can also move the `Func<>` into a normal function and just add the `indentedLines` closure as a param.

Comment: And it's only a few times bulkier than the code in the question ... :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Touche :-) - the `getNodeParent` hack has bloated what was otherwise fairly condensed.

Answer (score 0):

If we can store the current menu indices in an array:

```
object[] currentMenuIndices;
void addNodeAtNTabs(nodeInfo, currentMenuIndices) {
    currentPath = path;
    name = ns + "menu"
    foreach menuIndex in currentMenuIndices {
        currentPath = Descendants(name).ElementAt(menuIndex);
    }
    currentPath.Descendants(name).LastOrDefault().Add(nodeInfo);
}
```

The length of currentMenuIndices should be relative to the number of tabs the node is indented by.
*(Sorry if my codes seems like python)*